# AWS SES send_email() will not work for me, always "unexpected list element termination"

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Sounds like it should be strait forward to fix but I can't get it to work.

I've read the API reference for [send_email](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonSES/send_email)
I've read the other threads related to it, here and on other sites. I've used code samples to ensure my parameter arrays are nested properly (as best I can figure out) but everything gives "unexpected list element termination"

```
function amazonSesEmail($to, $subject, $message)
{
    $amazonSes = new AmazonSES(); //

    $response = $amazonSes->send_email('my_ses_confirmed_email@gmail.com',
        array('ToAddresses' => $to),
        array(
            'Subject.Data' => $subject,
            'Body.Text.Data' => $message,
        )
    );

    return $response;
}
```

I've also tried messy things like this in a desperate attempt to follow the reference structure:

```
$aws_reply = $aws_ses->send_email(  $fromEmailAddress, 
            array('ToAddresses' => 'same@gmail.com'),
                array(
                 array(  'Subject' => array('Data' => 'New Request '),
                         'Body' =>    array( 'Text' => array('Data' => 'New Request '))
                       )  
               )
);
```

In all cases when I print_r($response) this is the details:

```
CFResponse Object
(
    [header] => Array
        (
            [x-amzn-requestid] => xxxx-xxxxx
            [content-type] => text/xml
            [content-length] => 280
            [date] => Fri, 16 Dec 2011 03:24:07 GMT
            [_info] => Array
                (
                    [url] => https://xxxxx/
                    [content_type] => text/xml
                    [http_code] => 400
                    [header_size] => 166
                    [request_size] => 1088
                    [filetime] => -1
                    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
                    [redirect_count] => 0
                    [total_time] => 0.349242
                    [namelookup_time] => 0.156135
                    [connect_time] => 0.189468
                    [pretransfer_time] => 0.28083
                    [size_upload] => 185
                    [size_download] => 280
                    [speed_download] => 801
                    [speed_upload] => 529
                    [download_content_length] => 280
                    [upload_content_length] => 185
                    [starttransfer_time] => 0.349204
                    [redirect_time] => 0
                    [certinfo] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [method] => POST
                )

            [x-aws-stringtosign] => Fri, 16 Dec 2011 03:24:06 GMT68492574-F715-4AE3-B153-9446AE80866D
            [x-aws-request-headers] => Array
                (
                    [Content-Length] => 185
                    [Content-MD5] => 9+iobwTmkId+4ZmGt+6CDw==
                    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
                    [Date] => Fri, 16 Dec 2011 03:24:06 GMT
                    [Host] => xxxxxxxxxx.com
                    [X-Amz-Nonce] => xxx
                    [X-Amzn-Authorization] => AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=xxx,Algorithm=HmacSHA256,SignedHeaders=Content-Length;Content-MD5;Content-Type;Date;Host;X-Amz-Nonce,Signature=xxxx
                )

            [x-aws-body] => Action=SendEmail&Destination.ToAddresses=xxxx%40gmail.com&Message.Body.Text.Data=test%20body&Message.Subject.Data=test%20subject&Source=xxxxx%40gmail.com&Version=2010-12-01
        )

    [body] => CFSimpleXML Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [ns] => http://xxxx
                )

            [Error] => CFSimpleXML Object
                (
                    [Type] => Sender
                    [Code] => MalformedInput
                    [Message] => Unexpected list element termination
                )

            [RequestId] => xxxxx
        )

    [status] => 400
)
```

I am ripping my hair out over this as again, it should be SO strait forward but I can't seem to meet it's formatting requirements and what seems to work for others who've blogged about it will not work for me.  Any input from someone who's done this before would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I should add that I'm still in the SES sandbox and i'm trying to send from an authorized email to itself.

Comment: Was there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 9):

I also had this issue today that you were reporting.  After some messing about, I found that the following configuration works with the aws php sdk: sdk-1.5.3:

```
 $response = $ses->send_email($fromEmail,
      array('ToAddresses' => array($toEmail)),
           array(
                'Subject.Data' => $subject,
                'Body.Html.Data' => $content,
           )
 );
```

Looking at differences between yours and mine ...

```
 $response = $amazonSes->send_email('my_ses_confirmed_email@gmail.com',
 array('ToAddresses' => $to), // problem is here
      array(
           'Subject.Data' => $subject,
           'Body.Text.Data' => $message,
      )
 );
```

In both your examples you put the "to address, `$to`" not contained within an array.

Better late than never!

Comment: Thank you! I've been running in circles for two weeks on this problem with the latest Amazon SES package...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get that method working but I did get email sending through SES from php using the php PEAR package's MAIL extension. In the AWS dashoard you can setup your SES account to use SMTP authentication, so I did that and now SES lets me send mail as expected via smtp.

Hope this saves someone else out there some hours and headaches

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the way the list of to addresses has to be formatted; I was having a lot of trouble getting it to work with multiple recipients, but it's also devilishly tricky to get things going with just one ToAddress...

This might help you a little: [Sending emails to multiple recipients with Amazon SES](http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/sending-emails-multiple)

Using `CFComplexType::map()` helps ensure that things are in the proper structures for SES.